# Keras classification model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, classification

I need help to build keras model for classification.
I have

Input: 167 points of optical spectrum

Output 11 classes of investigated substance.

But in one data set can be spectre of substance with several substance (for example contains classes 2,3,4).
I tried to use `categorical_crossentropy`, but it is suitable only for non-intersecting classes.

[KerasDoc](https://keras.io/losses/):

> Note: when using the categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets should be in categorical format (e.g. if you have 10 classes, the target for each sample should be a 10-dimensional vector that is all-zeros expect for a 1 at the index corresponding to the class of the sample). In order to convert integer targets into categorical targets, you can use the Keras utility to_categorical:

My code:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=167))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(11))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I tried many models but can not get a good result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably go well with `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy` ([See here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207794/what-loss-function-for-multi-class-multi-label-classification-tasks-in-neural-n))

PS: This is not your case, but for a `categorial_crossentropy`, you should ideally use a `softmax` activation. The softmax outputs things optimized to maximize one class only.

(If anyone would like to complement this answer with a good or better "optimizer", feel free).

Comment: I tried use binary_crossentropy but on every fit action if check on random spectre i get prediction [ 0.23598771 0.24065545 0.20274314 0.20727901 0.21786793 0.20546967 0.24399549 0.23881513 0.22483987 0.24453731 0.2304628 ] But valid is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]. I cannot get any truth-like result.

Comment: You expect to get true values from "random spectre"? If you use `verbose=1` (or 2) in the fit method, you will be able to see the "loss" of your model decreasing. Also, you can use `epochs=someNumber` to repeat the training several times. If the loss decreases, the model is training ok, if it doesn't, there is a problem. I think that 167 data samples is too few for your model to learn things properly. I suggest some kind of data augmentation, such as creating composite (not random) spectres with different combinations of different substances you know.

Comment: One thing you must have in mind for small data samples: you can make your model train and predict them correctly, but if they're too few, there is a chance of your modeling be memorizing them instead of understanding them (it's called overfittin). If a model overfits, it seems great with training data, but different data not contained in training data won't have good results.